# How to extract Environment name from the cursor and Table name from the SQL query using Python

Tags: python, sql

The SQL query is written in a .txt file.
Developed Cursor to establish connection with database using Python.

My code is as below:

```
    connection = oracledb.connect(
        user="ABC",
        password="DEF",
        dsn="abcdefghi/ENV1")

    with open('C:\.........\FILE.txt','r',encoding="utf=8") as inserts:
        query = inserts.read()

    cursor.execute(query)
```

--> Need to extract Env name from the cursor.

--> Need table name from the query present in the text file.

These are the 2 requirements.